# Insert content to UI slider handle - UI Range Slider

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, rangeslider

I have created a range slider using UI library. By default it has it's slider handler. This slider handler is coming through the jQuery. You can inspect the snippet and understand it. Now what I want is, I want to place some text inside the slide handlers like,

[image]
[image]

So far I have tried this in both JS and CSS way which gave me no change.

CSS way (created the text as a PNG and pushed into a pseudo element)

```
#slider-range .ui-slider-handle:first-child:before {
  content: url('./images/min.png');
}
```

and JS way (used inner HTML in JS and also tried html() in jQuery).

```
  $('#slider-range .ui-slider-handle:first-child').html('<p>MIN<br><></p>');
  $('#slider-range .ui-slider-handle:last-child').html('<p>MAX<br><></p>');
```

I have gone through the UI documentation, but I couldn't find any helpful attribute to achieve this. Here is my snippet.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#slider-range").slider({
    range: true,
    min: 4500,
    max: 8000,
    values: [5000, 7500],
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      $("#amount").val("$" + ui.values[0] + " - $" + ui.values[1]);
    }
  });
  $("#amount").val("$" + $("#slider-range").slider("values", 0) +
    " - $" + $("#slider-range").slider("values", 1));
});
```

```css
.wrapper{
  padding:60px;
}
#slider-range>div {
  background: #ff6c00;
}
#slider-range .ui-state-default {
  background: #ffcc00;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);      
  border-radius: 7px;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 0px rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.23);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="slider-range"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**With only css**

You can use [`pseudo`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before) to the `.ui-slider-handle` with content `min/max`

```js
$(function() {
  $("#slider-range").slider({
    range: true,
    min: 4500,
    max: 8000,
    values: [5000, 7500],
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      $("#amount").val("$" + ui.values[0] + " - $" + ui.values[1]);
    }
  });
  $("#amount").val("$" + $("#slider-range").slider("values", 0) +
    " - $" + $("#slider-range").slider("values", 1));
});
```

```css
.wrapper{
  padding:60px;
}
#slider-range>div {
  background: #ff6c00;
}
#slider-range .ui-state-default {
  background: #ffcc00;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  border-radius: 7px;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 0px rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.23);
}
.ui-slider-handle:after{
content:"<>";
font-size:20px;
padding-left: 8px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 21px;
    right: 15px;
}
.ui-slider-handle:before{
content:"min";
font-size:20px;
padding-left: 8px;
}
.ui-slider-handle:last-child:before{
content:"max";
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="slider-range"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a great work. Thank you for your time. Before I am working with this I want to one thing, Is this responsive effective? I am asking this question because of the absolute position.

Comment: as I see yes it responsive...(try to change the size of browser) but you can work with percent instead `px`

Comment: That sounds great. Thank you brother ;-)

Comment: happy to help(I am sister:))